# Capturing realtime price in webpage or from a webpage title

Tags: macos, safari, html

I am using a Safari browser on a MAC system. I started day-trading with Safari on the website https://bittrex.com/Market/Index?MarketName=BTC-URO

Is there a way in which I can be notified/view regarding the last price (top right) of the item when safari is minimised (e.g., when I am working on a word doc)? Do note that the last price also gets displayed & updated on the title of the webpage.

Is there a way to get the live price when safari is minimised? I am not sure if there is widget or app in MAC OS that lets you capture this specific detail on a web page or even capture the web page title. Or is there a script that let you do this?

Thanks in advance

P.S- I don't know too much programming, so please bear with me for a easy solution.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for tools or methods for automating Safari, without programming.

Comment: I have limited knowledge but if you can suggest something, then I can try. Thanks for the reply.